# List iteration type mismatch

Tags: java, swing, collections, jtabbedpane

```
List holder = new List();
holder.add(new JTabbedPane());
holder.add(new JTabbedPane());

for(JTabbedPane tab : holder)
{
    System.out.println(tab.toString());
}
```

Why it is showing error on type mismatch in for-each loop?

Comment: which list is this? -> `List holder = new List();`

Comment: Try new ArrayList<JTabbedPane>(); instead

Comment: you have to show us your `List` class, because `java.util.List` is an interface, so you can't instantiate it, and the first line of code you posted won't compile.

Comment: List holder = new List();   must not be java.util.List()

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this

```
ArrayList<JTabbedPane> holder = new ArrayList<JTabbedPane>();
        holder.add(new JTabbedPane());
        holder.add(new JTabbedPane());
        for (JTabbedPane jTabbedPane : holder) {
            System.out.println(holder.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
for(Object tab : holder)
{
System.out.println( ( (JTabbedPane )tab).toString());
}
```

It is showing error because holder  `is List of Object , not List of JTabbedPane`. So when you use for-each loop with `for(JTabbedPane tab : holder)` , It will show compilation error.